# How to find basis of ker(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working with the following kernel: $\ker\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, which I simplified to  $\ker \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $.

I want to find the basis of $\ker A$. I took "1" in the first row as the bound variable, and "-1" as the free variable, so that the first row has the equation: $x_2-x_3=0$, and assigned $x_3 = \alpha$. In the end I got only the base $\left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)$, but I am supposed to find two basis. Where I did wrong?

Comment: It appears $(1,0,0)$ also gets mapped to $0 $ under this matrix :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I don't know how to find it :/

Comment: Find what exactly?

Comment: The other base.

Comment: Do you see that $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ are linearly independent?

Comment: The base consists of a third vector too, though.

Comment: Thank you @DionelJaime, but how did you know that (1,0,0) is another base?

Comment: The free variables are exactly the variables suchh that there is no pivot in the corresponding column of the echelon form. There is no pivot in the first column, so $x_1$ is free.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, that's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, $x_1$ is a free variable. So letting $x_1 = s$ and $x_3 = t$, an element of the kernel is of the form
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
s\\ t\\ t
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
s\\ 0\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ t\\ t
\end{pmatrix}
=
s
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
t
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix} \, .
\end{align*}
This shows that $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,1)^T$ span the kernel, and one can show that they are also linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

The rank of the matrix is $1$, therefore the nullity is $2$.  Any two linearly independent vectors in the kernel will do.  You already have two:  $\{\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\}$.